# Динамическое добавление html-тегов

Tags: php, html

С чего начать в этом вопросе? Какие возможности php надо использовать? Пытаюсь создать что-то вроде блога, надо чтобы пользователь написал, и это сохранялось при обновлении страницы.
Хорошие ссылки приветствую.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

База данных, что же ещё. Но без знаний PHP, я не знаю, что Вы будете делать..

Comment: С php, mysql знаком, довольно много работаю с ними. Интересует, что конкретно, какой раздел изучать, чтобы это осуществить. Например, регулярные выражения или что-то ещё...

Comment: Если вы довольно много с ним работаете, то довольно странно видеть такой вопрос

Comment: Всё разобрался.

Answer (score 0):

[Самоучитель PHP](http://www.softtime.ru/bookphp/gl1_1.php)
и конечно же
[онлайн справка по HTML](http://htmlbook.ru/).

Читай, учись. От простого к сложному.

Answer (score 0):

Лучшее решение - WordPress:) Или написание собственной системы управления сайтом.  Есть  [ссылка](http://srs.myrusakov.ru/html/). Там написано, что это курс по HTML, но в конце там идут уроки по PHP. Обучение построено в виде email-рассылки.

Answer (score 0):

Дабы не вводить в ступор, вот html код:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Тест</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div>Это div</div>
    </div>
    <button>Добавить еще</button>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('button').click(function() {
               $('<div>А это еще div</div>').appendTo('.container');
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

А дальше в гугл смотри почему оно так работает

Comment: Всё разобрался всем спасибо.